# My printer shows that there is still ink in the cartridge, but does not print this color

Tags: printer, ink

I have a HP printer. I hadn't used it for a while. All toners were almost empty. I bought new ones and installed them.

I needed to print ca. 170 pages consisting of colorful pictures and text. Everything was fine for the first hundred or so.  Suddenly, the quality of the printouts worsened. I managed to verify that it looked like the black ink run out. I printed out some text in black and it was light grey. I also printed out other colors and there were fine.

I'd say that the ink ran out and I should buy a new cartridge. But I checked the ink levels on my printer and I was ca. 75% full. Cartridges with colorful inks were ca. 50% full.

I tried to print a sudoku template- the black lines were actually black. I tried printing from other programs and the problem still occured. I also tried cleaning up the print head, printing the healthcheck report of my printer. Nothing helped.

The old black cartridge works as the new one, but it makes sense, since it is empty.

Is there something wrong with my printer or with the ink cartridge?  How can I check it? Any help will be appreciated.

**Update**: the printer model is HP Deskjet Ink Advantage 3525.

Comment: ink and toner are two totally different things.  It sounds like you are using ink and using the word "toner" instead of "cartridge"

Comment: The title still says "toner".  What is the printer model?

Comment: @fixer1234, I fixed it. Thanks. I will be able to check the printer model in a few hours. I'll update the question then.

Comment: Are the ink cartridges HP retail, HP refilled, or third party, and how fresh are they?

Comment: I would say that you haven't managed to clean up well the print head, or that there is a hardware problem with the printer (probably not worth repairing).

Comment: @fixer1234, the ink cartidges are HP retail, I bought them a week ago, carried them in my backpack for a few days, installed them and started printing.

Comment: HP warranties the cartridges.  They may exchange them for you.